# Applying characteristic distance and time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, dimensional-analysis

> Q: Consider the 1 -dimensional motion of a particle in the potential $V(x)=g|x|^{\alpha}$. Let $t$ and $d$ denote the characteristic time and distance, respectively, for this motion. Show by dimensional analysis that
> $$
> t \propto d^{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}
> $$
> Apply this result to (a) the harmonic oscillator, (b) a particle in free fall on the surface of the earth, and (c) a planet falling radially toward a star.

I've been able to solve the first part fairly simply, deriving it using dimensional analysis as the problem requests.
\begin{array}{r}
g|x|^{\alpha}=M^{2} \frac{\left[d^{2}\right]}{\left[t^{2}\right]} \\
t^{2}=m^{2} * \frac{\left[d^{2}\right]}{g \cdot|x|^{\alpha}} \\
t^{2} \propto d^{2-\alpha} \\
t \propto d^{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}
\end{array}
However, I don't really understand how to apply this interesting result to the harmonic oscillator, let alone parts b and c. Does this result imply that the unit of time is always proportional to a specific distance? I feel as if though I am missing the significance of this result.

Comment: This one is confusing me just in general. What does this mean: “..motion of a particle in the potential ()” ? Im *quite* curious. Potential energy in a field, of a nonlinear spring? But if a spring, that tells us the potential energy at a location? Do we know the initial conditions? What if we are already motionless at min V, which is x=0.. nothing happens. Can you decipher my confusion from that rant? Pls 

Comment: @AlBrown I’m not sure I understand.  This is a motion where the force law will be given by $F=-dV/dx$.  Thus in general the force will be position-dependent - it usually is.  One does not need to identify the origin of the potential or the force.

Comment: are you sure you need $m^2$ (or $M^2$)?  The kinetic energy is $mv^2/2$, with a single power of mass.

Comment: Ugh. I just figured it out i think. It’s oscillating which we know because given a characteristic time and d. Yes i knew force varied with time. So it’s saying that the potential **energy** is V, and at x=0 we’ll have max kinetic and at x=d no motion. Is that what this describes?

Comment: @AlBrown there’s no guarantee that $x=d$ is a fixed point of motion, just that the motion occurs over a length of typical size $d$.  This is a scaling argument, not a precise description of the motion.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Ok appreciate it. That means (and youre saying) characteristic length and time are both parameters of that particular force vs distance relationship. And they are calculated based on some benchmark type oscillating situation that probably isnt exactly the real world happening. In fact, oscillation itself may not be happening. Thanks again i see now and will review characteristic d and t. What threw me off was the words “ motion of a particle in the potential ()” being used to mean “a particle under an force vs x relationship that gives a potential energy of v(x)” thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the unit of time is always proportional to a specific distance

The relevant timescale scales with the relevant lengthscale to some power, yes.

For a hamonic oscillator, $V\propto x^2$ so $\alpha=2$ and $t \propto d^0 = 1$. I.e. for a harmonic oscillator, the relevant timescale (i.e. the *period*) does *not* depend on space, i.e. it is not a function of position, but a constant. You can easily check this against the periods for a spring (only depends on spring constant $k$ and mass $m$) and pendulum (length $\ell$ and acceleration $g$).

For a particle in free fall on the surface of the Earth, $V\propto mgx$ so $\alpha=1$ and and $t\propto d^{1/2}$. From the suvat equation, the time for a projectile to reach and fall from a height $h$ scales as $\sqrt{h}$ so it checks out.

Finally, for planetary motion you would use Newton's formula so $V\propto 1/x$, so $\alpha=-1$ and hence $t\propto d^{3/2}$. Kepler's third law says that the orbital period of planets in an elliptical orbit of semi-major axis $a$ goes as $T\propto \sqrt{a^3} \propto a^{3/2}$. So, again, it checks out.

Comment: Please see my question above if willing, it’s a comment under the question, if it doesnt automatically appear to you as well

Comment: A potential $V(x)$ causes a force $F=-dV/dx$, and a force $F$ changes the particle's position by $F = m d^2x/dt^2$. So "motion of a particle in the potential ()" means the trajectory $x(t)$ the particle traces out in both space and time.

Comment: Thanks. It was the wording. Completely separate thought: “Apply to.. (b) a particle in free fall *on the surface of the earth*.., and (c) a planet falling **radially** toward a star.” Not orbit for c, rather is also free fall right? I think the difference theyre trying to get is b being assumed constant g (on earth’s surface) and c we should account for distance as we go, via F= G(m1m2/r^2)

Comment: @AlBrown I am free-fall in the end means you have something pulling you down. That's Newton Gmm/r2, which for constant g (close to the surface), is just mg

Comment: I can see how orbit could be called a type of free fall, kindve. But “A planet falling **radially** toward a star.” doesnt sound like orbit to me. But ok.